# How to remove date on sticky posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, sticky

How would I remove the date from sticky posts in Wordpress? In my template-tags.php file I currently have the following:

```
<div class="entry-meta">
    <span class="posted-on"><?php _e( 'Posted on', 'graphy' ); ?>
        <?php printf( '<a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published"           datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a>',
            esc_url( get_permalink() ),
            esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_date() )
        ); 
           ?>

    </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a conditional to check whether the current post (you must be in the loop) is sticky

```
<div class="entry-meta"> 
  <?php if( !is_sticky() ): ?>
     <!-- Put your <span class="posted-on"> here -->
  <?php endif; ?>
```